# Set global cache false

Tags: grails, caching, global, browser-cache

Using `cache false` in a Grails 2.4.5 controller method I can prevent grails from caching the response.

Want to set this property for all methods by default without using this statement. Is that possible?

```
def loginHandshake = {
    cache false

    // do here the hard work
    ...
    response.outputStream << "OK ${session.id}"
}
```

Comment: Is it standard grails? I did not know of a cache property.
Can you show me where it is documented? I imagine that I can use it in my projects too.

Answer (score 0):

You can define like in your Config:

```
cache.headers.enabled = false
```

From the docs: https://grails.org/plugin/cache-headers